# need to convert sql join query with count into linq and pass it to view

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
 select COUNT([User].UserId)
    from [User] join Team on [User].TeamId = Team.TeamId where Team.TeamId =2
```

Here's what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to implement

```
 var countUser = from u in db.Users
                            join t in db.Teams
                            on u.TeamId equals t.TeamId
                            where (u.TeamId == 11)
                            select new
                            {
                            };
```

Comment: here is a really good place to start learning Linq and it has numerous examples as well [C# Linq Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var countUser = (from u in db.Users
                            join t in db.Teams
                            on u.TeamId equals t.TeamId
                            where (u.TeamId == 11)
                            select new
                            {
                              u.UserId  
                            }).Count();
```

Comment: i have done this on my index action method and i have to pass this result to view and the index method already return something to view . please help